# Is it possible to send multiple commands to vagrant ssh via a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, vagrant

I'm on a Windows host using Git Bash to run the `.sh` files.

---

There are 4 components to my current project. To start up it on localhost, I have to:

1. `webdriver-manager start` since I'm the QA and need that running anyway
2. `vagrant up` in the project's parent folder, then close out that window (or just start the VM myself via VirtualBox UI)
3. `vagrant ssh` `cd /vagrant` `cd "component's folder"` `docker-compose up` x 4
4. `grunt serve`

Right now, I have a `.sh` file each for 1, 2, and 4, but I cannot find how to pass along multiple commands to vagrant ssh, especially since `docker-compose up` needs to be constantly running.

Is there a way to pass along those `cd`s and the docker-compose?

---

I found [the ssh documentation from vagrant](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html) which mentions something about needing to do fancy things to get it running background processes, but I have no idea what it's doing or how to implement that in a `.sh` file since the wording is so wishy-washy.

Also, I'm new to shell scripts in general, so if there's a smarter way to go about this to solve the issue, I'd appreciate it, too. These scripts aren't *necessary*, I just don't want to have to type it repeatedly every day when I'm running my tests locally.

Comment: What do you mean `x 4` there? You need to run `docker-compose up` four times from the same directory? Did you mean you have four components and you need to run `docker-compose up` in each directory?

Comment: 4 components that I need to run `docker-compose up` on. So I end up having 5 instances of Git Bash running before I can start up my tests, which is why I'm hoping to optimize setting up all those windows to save me time each morning / reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your Vagrantfile, have something like this

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
echo "running script in the VM"
cd /vagrant
cd "component's folder"
docker-compose up
cd "component's folder 2"
docker-compose up
# and add all other commands you would run from the VM
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ....
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
  ....
end
```

Note: this will run the commands as sudo (from your VM) if you want to run them as your vagrant user, just do

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: "false"
```

Answer (score 4):

If the commands needs to be invoked on `vagrant up`, you can provide [provisioning script](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) available on the host machine by:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: '/vagrant/scripts/provision.sh'
```

so Vagrant will then upload this script into the guest and execute it (using URL instead of path would also work),

Alternatively you may use inline shell syntax:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello, World"
```

Or to run the script within VM, then try:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: %Q(/usr/bin/env VAR=1 bash /vagrant/script.sh)
```

---

To run one-time off commands in VM, you may use `vagrant ssh` command for that, for example:

```
vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant && echo Hello, World"
```

Comment: when I try the last suggestion, I get 'cannot exceute binary file'.

    vagrant ssh -c "echo 'blah'"
    /bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
    Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.